# .NET File Stream write method writes all empty lines

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

I am having a C# console application access files over a network and write to it. I noticed that some files have been corrupted and have only null written to them. I did not get any exceptions. 
I am using simple code that writes a byte array to the file's stream. When opening the files in Binary mode, all i see are Zeros, something like "0: 00 00 00 00 
10: 00 00 00 00".

Does anyone know why such a thing would happen? There could have been a network failure, but network failures should have thrown some IO exceptions right?

Let me know if anyone has any idea about this.

Code sample:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
using (FileStream fs = fi.Open (FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
   fs.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?  I think I am getting the same type of behaviour.  I noticed a article about reading data from a file stream, is perhaps not as straight forward as one might think. http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html

Answer (score 9):

Make sure to call FileStream.Flush() where appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're closing the file.

Comment: The code is within an using block, so file closing should not be the problem. Besides this problem just occurred to a few files, a lot of files have been saved successfully.

Answer (score 2):

As **tzerb** above mentioned his code, I thought it would be best to add another layer, a try/catch to check and see if the exception is indeed being caught - I am surprised that no exception occurred but worth a shot

```
try{
  FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath); 
  using (FileStream fs = fi.Open (FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) 
  { 
    fs.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length); 
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
  }
}catch(System.Security.SecurityException secEx){
  Console.WriteLine("SecurityException caught: {0}", secEx.ToString());
}catch(System.IO.IOException ioEx){
  Console.WriteLine("IOException caught: {0}", ioEx.ToString());
}
```

Confirm then if you did indeed get the message 'IOException caught: ...'

**Edit:** Have added a security exception to see if it has something to do with permissions?

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: This file write code is actually within a try catch block. Let me add the IO exception handler and see if there is anything getting caught.

Comment: @Srijanani: Ok, Now that you mentioned it is within the try/catch - I think you should edit your post to include the try/catch. I have thought of something else that could be tripping up...see my edited code above...this is a shooting myself in the foot... :)

Comment: @Srijanani: If you still do not see any exception caught in the console, then I am stumped - could be a broken network connection at the point when it writes to the file? What's the filename you are using? Are you using UNC in a verbatim string i.e. @"\\MyServer\foobar.dat"?

Answer (score 0):

That's a new one.  My guess is that an exception is getting lost in the downstream code with the FileStream object is destroyed.  I'd start by changing the code to do everything explictly:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath); 
using (FileStream fs = fi.Open (FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) 
{ 
    fs.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length); 
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}
```

The next thing I'd do is make sure the data you're writing is as expected and then that nothing else is modifying the files.